Unable to import custom package in Azure Synapse notebook after successful installation
Problem Description
I am trying to import a custom Python package named check_excel_errors in an Azure Synapse notebook. The package was installed successfully using pip, but when I try to import it, I encounter syntax and module errors.
What I've Done So Far

Installed the package (I had previously uploaded it as a wheel file to the Spark pool packages).
Verified packet installation:
Checked the package details:
Checked if the installation path is in sys.path:
Tried importing the package, with the following error:
Tried importing it with dashes, witht the following error:

Here is the content of the init.py file within the package:
from .models.validation_result import ValidationResult
from .queries.validation_queries import (
    get_numeric_validation_query,
    get_missing_values_query,
    get_duplicates_query,
    PRODUCT_CODE_VALIDATION
)

__all__ = [
    'ValidationResult',
    'get_numeric_validation_query',
    'get_missing_values_query',
    'get_duplicates_query',
    'PRODUCT_CODE_VALIDATION'
]

I have also tried restarting the notebook kernel, to no avail.
So, why am I unable to import the package despite it being installed, and how can I resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Can you share the configuration of your spark cluster?

I have tried to install the check_excel_errors package like you:
%pip install check_excel_errors
%pip show check_excel_errors

But I am getting the below Error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
check_excel_errors (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching
distribution found for check_excel_errors

I have tried to use check_excel_errors inside   requirment.txt method to upload the packages to spark pool
that did not work.
In Python module you mentioned init.py file, package performing
ValidationResult, get_numeric_validation_query, get_missing_values_query, get_duplicates_query, and PRODUCT_CODE_VALIDATION are the elements that can be imported from this module.
As a workaround I have tried using pyspark:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
Numeric Validation (e.g., price > 0)
numeric_validation = df.filter(F.col("price") <= 0)
missing_values = df.filter(F.col("price").isNull() | F.col("quantity").isNull())
duplicates = df.groupBy("product_code").count().filter(F.col("count") > 1)
product_code_validation = df.filter(~F.col("product_code").rlike("^P\\d{3}$"))

Results:

Numeric Validation (Invalid Prices):
+---+-----+------------+--------+
| id|price|product_code|quantity|
+---+-----+------------+--------+
|  4|-10.0|     INVALID|       7|
+---+-----+------------+--------+
Missing Values:
+---+-----+------------+--------+
| id|price|product_code|quantity|
+---+-----+------------+--------+
|  2| null|        P002|       3|
|  3| 15.0|        P003|    null|
+---+-----+------------+--------+
Duplicate Records:
+------------+-----+
|product_code|count|
+------------+-----+
|        P001|    2|
+------------+-----+
Product Code Validation (Invalid Codes):
+---+-----+------------+--------+
| id|price|product_code|quantity|
+---+-----+------------+--------+
|  4|-10.0|     INVALID|       7|
+---+-----+------------+--------+


